# Adaptive cards version 1.3

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Can anyone tell me how can we use adaptive card version 1.3, When I'm using any card with version 1.3 and viewing it in-app studio it says?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried an adaptive card of version 1.3 both in App Studio and MS Teams and it worked fine.Could you please try upgrading your version and check if it works. Attaching the json below which i tested:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "speak": "Tom's Pie is a pizza restaurant which is rated 9.3 by customers.",
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "PIZZA"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Tom's Pie",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "extraLarge",
              "spacing": "none"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "4.2 ★★★☆ (93) · $$",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "spacing": "none"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "**Matt H. said** \"I'm compelled to give this place 5 stars due to the number of times I've chosen to eat here this past year!\"",
              "size": "small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
              "label": "Select a user",
              "isMultiSelect": false,
              "choices": [
                {
                  "title": "User 1",
                  "value": "User1"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 2",
                  "value": "User2"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 3",
                  "value": "User3"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 4",
                  "value": "User4"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 5",
                  "value": "User5"
                }
              ],
              "style": "filtered"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://picsum.photos/300?image=882",
              "size": "auto"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "More Info",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to update app studio and for teams which version of botbuilder are you using

Comment: We are using Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26376 (64-bit) and Bot builder Version="4.13.2"